# Maintain scroll position with CDK autosize virtual scroll strategy

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

Maintain scroll position with CDK autosize virtual scroll strategy

I have a large list of items that can be scrolled with `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport autosize>` provided by `@angular/cdk-experimental` (the items have dynamic heights, thus I'm using this scroll strategy instead of the `FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy`).

New items are inserted in the list over time, i.e. they are appended on top. When the user scrolls down I want to avoid that new items will push the items in the viewport away. Therefore I need a mechanism to maintain / restore the scroll position after the items have been added.

I have a semi-working solution (and hacky because it reads private fields), but the viewport shifts a few pixels randomly after items have been added.

Here are the relevant code parts:

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

...

// After new items have been added:

const offset = this.viewport.measureScrollOffset('top');
const topPosition = offset + newItems.length * this.viewport['_scrollStrategy']._averager._averageItemSize; // the autosize strategy determines an average item size I'm trying to use to determine how the viewport should be shifted

this.viewport.scrollTo({
  top: topPosition
});
```

I created a demo of this approach here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be926g?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.ts

Any ideas how to achieve this seamlessly with a constant viewport?

Comment: You can consider storing the new data in another property and having a notification at the top of the scroll window, when new data is received, the user decide whether they need to load the new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `this.viewport.getRenderedRange()` to check the viewport is on top and if zero then append the elements else keep the elements in a bucket and append the objects when user scrolled to top of viewport.

```
  const range = this.viewport.getRenderedRange();
  console.log("range", range);
  bucket = [...bucket, ...newItems];
  console.log("bucket", bucket);
  if (range.start == 0) {
    this.items = [...bucket.reverse(), ...this.items];
    bucket = [];
  }
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be926g-pxgyk8?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.ts)